# Why do the Engineers' ships in Prometheus look that uncomfortable?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

The Engineers share our DNA and we basically came from them, so why do their ships appear to be so uncomfortable? Surely they need to sit and lie down but the only place we saw anything like this was on the the control deck. Stasis pods and a control seat but the rest of the ship looked as though it was designed for a totally different species. The floors in the corridors were uneven and seemed unpleasant to walk on. The only soft items in the ship were the squishy buttons.

Yes, I know of the size difference and evolution but the ship they had built for themselves did not seem ergonomically suited for bipeds.

Comment: Where did it say that we shared their DNA or came from them? It was my understanding that the Engineers engineered us, but that is not necessarily the same thing as us being genetic descendents.

Comment: @phantom42 - Dr. Shaw analized the DNA from the dead engineer and it matched human.

Comment: It may just be that the way their gene expression works that they don't fatigue the same way we do... maybe their subspecies (they do register as human, not sure if it better to refer to them as breed\strain\subspecies) has bred\engineered out the need for creature comforts, all they do is work. It could also be that crew areas were sealed off and the scanners couldn't detect them, or they are just such absolute essentialists that if they aren't actively working on a project they are in hypersleep to preserve resources.

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be a canon answer.

But the Captain theorized that the planet they were on was a military installation.

You generally tend to see less creature comforts in military barracks.

The flight deck - the only thing that mattered - WAS as you noted ergonomically suited.